# Cannot read property of undefined when press button angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

sorry to ask a simple question here. But I really don't know how to fix it or why I got this error :(

I got this error use angular 1.x. What I want here is about make an alert when user press a button without input the title in the form.

Here's my code, I make it simpler btw :D

**index.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Title</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="shipment_template.title" class="form-control">
</div>



<button ng-click="check">Check This</button>
```

And I put the logic in my controller:

**shipmentTemplate.controller.js**

```
if (typeof $scope.shipment_template.title == 'undefined') {

    console.log("success")
} else {

    alert("Please fill the title")
}
```

The problem is when I fill the input, I get the `success` in my console, But when I not fill it I don't get any alert, instead I got this error.

`Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

first I try it without use typeof, and use length, but it give the same error :(

Sorry for my bad english, and I hope you all can help me fix this guys :-D

Comment: You need to define `shipment_template` in the controller, use `$scope.shipment_template = {}`

Comment: Oww yeah it works :D, thanks sir!

Comment: Or just pass in the ng-model value (`shipment_template.title`) to the ng-click function (see my example below)

Comment: Oh it works too, I don't know if this problems can fixed with many ways. Thank you sir :-D

Comment: So many solutions, but best practice is what @Satpal suggested.

Comment: suggestion from @Satpal will really make it if I use more than 1 input, I think XD

Comment: The way I suggested that is use of ng-init will also works, but you must use shipment_template.property after ng-init. Anyways, the best practice is to define in controller. Because if you are using controller at another place, no need to worry if defined in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the model into your check function and that should do the trick:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="">Title</label>
 <input type="text" ng-model="shipment_template.title" class="form-control">
</div>

<button ng-click="check(shipment_template.title)">Check This</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
  $scope.check = function(input) {
    if (input) {
      console.log("success");
    }
    else {
      alert("Please fill the title");
    }
  }
```

It's also a clearer way to write the code you're trying to accomplish. Working Code: [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/6XwhJ9FKRl3heztkl9gv?p=preview)

Comment: Sir, I think it should `if (input)` not `if (!input)` XD. But Thank you this way fix my problem

Comment: You're welcome :)That's what I originally thought, but your original logic says `typeof $scope.shipment_template.title == 'undefined'`, which means `"if the title is undefined then console.log success"`. I assumed that for some reason this was your expected behavior. Regardless, I changed the answer to reflect what normal validation would look like (if there's an input, output success - if there's not an input, prompt the user to fill in the input)

Answer (score 0):

You could init your `shipment_template` in your controller like this :

**shipmentTemplate.controller.js**

```
$scope.shipment_template = {'title':''};
```